# Native Plugin written in C# EntryPointNotFoundException

Tags: c#, plugins, unity-game-engine

I am trying to develop a native plugin for Unity (using Unity 2017.1.0f3 and VS 2015). The target platform for my native plugin is UWP and the plugin is written in C#.

Below are the code for my plugin and my script in Unity.

Plugin code in a Class Library targeting Windows 10 14393

```
public static class SettingsService
    {
        public static string GetSetting( string key )
        {
            var localSettings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
            try
            {
                var stringvalue = localSettings.Values[key] as string;
                return stringvalue;
            }
            catch ( ArgumentNullException en )
            {
                return default( string );
            }
        }

        public static void SaveSetting( string key, string value )
        {
            var localSettings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
            localSettings.Values[key] = value;
        }
    }
```

Unity script code

```
public class TestNativePlugin : MonoBehaviour {

    [DllImport( "UnityPluginTestUWP", EntryPoint = "GetSetting" )]
    private static extern string GetSetting( string key );

    [DllImport( "UnityPluginTestUWP", EntryPoint = "SaveSetting" )]
    private static extern void SaveSetting( string key, string value );
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {    
        SaveSetting( "setting", "oeoeoe" );
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine( GetSetting( "setting" ) );
    }    
}
```

The problem is that in runtime I get an `EntryPointNotFoundException` with the message : 
**Unable to find an entry point named 'SaveSetting' in DLL UnityPluginTestUWP.dll'**

I have read online that this may occur because of mangling of function names by the compiler. But this was only in C++ code. My plugin is written in C#.

Any help to overcome this is welcome.

Comment: Why are you importing DLL how if was writen in C++? directly include your dll in your asset folder and use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have in your question is an managed plugin. You only need to use `DllImport` and `extern` if you are making a native C++ plugin with another C# plugin that wraps around it. That's not the case here since I don't see any C++ code.

A simple managed plugin from Unity's [Doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UsingDLL.html):

```
namespace DLLTest {

    public class MyUtilities {

        public int c;

        public void AddValues(int a, int b) {
            c = a + b;  
        }

        public static int GenerateRandom(int min, int max) {
            System.Random rand = new System.Random();
            return rand.Next(min, max);
        }
    }
}
```

Compile it and put the .dll file in your Unity `<project folder>/Assets` folder

Usage:

```
public class Test : MonoBehaviour {

     void Start () {
        MyUtilities utils = new MyUtilities();
        utils.AddValues(2, 3);
        print("2 + 3 = " + utils.c);
     }

     void Update () {
        print(MyUtilities.GenerateRandom(0, 100));
     }
}
```

---

If you are going to use any Unity function or API in the managed plugin, you have to also add `UnityEngine.dll` as reference to your plugin before building it. Simply right click on the *Solution Explorer* and choose *Add Reference* then look for `UnityEngine.dll`  in the following folder below:

You can find this on Windows at:

```
Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Managed\UnityEngine.dll
```

You can find this on Mac OSX at:

```
Applications/Unity.app/Contents/Frameworks/Managed/UnityEngine.dll
```

Comment: I think I may have the wrong idea as to what native/managed plugins are. I said that it was a native plugin because it includes code like `var localSettings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;` that cannot be compiled by Unity since it is UWP specific. But you are saying that my plugin is still a managed plugin (because it is written in C# a managed language) am I right?

Comment: You are welcome. Always try the solution before commenting.